# existence of discrete compound in Lebesgue decomposition theorem

Tags: probability, reference-request

Im in the process of understanding the proof of the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem (the version where the measure is decomposed into 3 measures: the discrete, the absolute continuous and the singular compound). But i cant really find any proof online for the existence of the discrete part.
Any help or recommendations would be appreciated.

please excuse my english im not a native speaker.

Comment: The singular part can be decompose into a continuous part and a *purely jump* or *purely atomic* part . I think the jump part is the part that bothers you.

Comment: yes thank you :) do you have any ideas where i can find more about the existence of this parts?

Comment: Any book on Lebesgue integration will cover the Radon-Nikodym decomposition of a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ with respect to another $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$: $d\nu=f\,d\mu+\nu_s$ where $\nu_s$ is singular with respect to $\mu$. Then, focusing on $\nu_s$ we can further decompose $\nu_s=\nu_{cs}+\nu_{ds}$ where $\nu_{ds}$ is the *discrete part*. This is easy to do since the number of atoms is at most countable. F. Jones, Lebegue integration on Euclidean space devotes a section on this type of decomposition for monotone functions on the real line from where the result follows for measures

Comment: thank you very much!